# How do I use a custom tokenizer with mt5?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm new to ML in general. I'm attempting to use mt5 as a practice.

I trained an mt5 model for MT, but would like to now use a custom tokenizer. I have pre-made a BPE tokenizer and saved it as per the [huggingface docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/fast_tokenizers).

I know I can do:

```
from transformers import MT5Model, T5Tokenizer

model = MT5Model.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
article = "UN Offizier sagt, dass weiter verhandelt werden muss in Syrien."
summary = "Weiter Verhandlung in Syrien."
inputs = tokenizer(article, return_tensors="pt")
with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    labels = tokenizer(summary, return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model(input_ids=inputs["input_ids"], decoder_input_ids=labels["input_ids"])
hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

as per [the docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/mt5) and I assume I can just load my tokenizer instead of Google's but I'm sure what happens after this, I don't know where the hidden_states go or what to do with that after that snippet.

This is what I have so far:

```
model_args = T5Args()
model_args.max_seq_length = 64
model_args.train_batch_size = 15
model_args.eval_batch_size = 15
model_args.num_train_epochs = 20
model_args.evaluate_during_training = True
model_args.evaluate_during_training_steps = 30000
model_args.use_multiprocessing = False
model_args.fp16 = False
model_args.save_steps = -1
model_args.save_eval_checkpoints = False
model_args.no_cache = True
model_args.reprocess_input_data = True
model_args.overwrite_output_dir = True
model_args.preprocess_inputs = False
model_args.num_return_sequences = 1

model = T5Model("mt5", "google/mt5-base", args=model_args)
```

After this I pretty much just do: `model.train_model(train_df, eval_data=eval_df)`

to train it.

Where should I go about inserting the custom tokenizer? I can't figure it out...

The main question:

- I want to add a custom tokenizer to the mt5 model, I do understand that, according to the docs, I can just preload one (which I have already created and saved). My question is, what do I do after the snippet that I posted up top? I am unsure what happens after `hidden_states` given that the approach I used, currently, has no need of any of it. That is, the current approach I have just uses the `T5Args()` I mentioned above and I train with that.

Comment: Would you mark the main question in a more clear way?

Comment: @meti I added a final paragraph. Let me know if that helps, please

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to spot on here!

**First** of all, keep in your mind that every transformer model has had a long pre-training phase on the massive corpus. This phase is helping model with having a general idea about any word in any context. In most cases, this phase can't be done properly and completely by individual researchers.

**Every word recognized by the tokenizer has a corresponding entry in the embedding layer** (the very first layer of the model), if the new tokenizer assigned a different `token_id` to the word it eliminates all knowledge that has been gained by the model.

The only reasonable way to **manipulate tokenizer** in transformers architecture is adding new words (if they weren't included) and then finetune on a customized corpus based on the task at hand.

Comment: first off, thanks for the explanation.

Secondly, I was looking at implementing this: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/mt5#transformers.MT5Model but then, based on what you tell me (if I understood correctly) would that mean that it's better to add instead of replace entirely the tokenizer?